# sap.m.TileContainer issue

Tags: sapui5

I am using `sap.m.TileContainer` to show tiles,

```
var tileContainer = new sap.m.TileContainer({
                tiles:  {
                    path: "/Buttons",
                    template: new sap.m.StandardTile({
                        title : "{name}",
                        visible : "{active}"
                    })
                }
            });
```

My odata service:-

```
{
d: [
    {
       __metadata: {
          id: "http://host/Service.svc/Buttons(2)",
       },
       ID: 2,
       DisplayName: "Work",
       Active: true
   },
   {
      __metadata: {
          id: "http://host/Service.svc/Buttons(3)",
      },
      ID: 3,
      DisplayName: "In",
      Active: true
  }
 ]
}
```

working fine.

Now when I changed the Active in OData model of 1st tile to `false`, I don't get any tiles on the UI.

Error as -

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '$' of undefined
```

Again I tried changing the 2nd tile Active to `false` and 1st one to `true`, which working fine, showing the 1st tile and hiding the 2nd one.

Please help, Thank you

Added Version And error msg-

SAPUI5 Version  1.34.8, 
Core Version    1.34.8 (built at 20160226-0945, last change )
[image]

Comment: could you please provide jsbin?

Comment: Is your active property really `false`? or does it get removed from the model? have you tried to force it to boolean: `visible: "{= !!${active} }"` ?

Comment: I am updating it to Active : false, it is still there (not removing so that I can make it visible again when I want). It is strange as it works on 2nd tile and so on... not working only on the 1st one.

Comment: Please turn on debug sources (Ctrl+Alt+Shift+P) and tell us, where exactly the error you mentioned occurs (File and line). And also please tell us which Version of UI5 you are using.

Comment: @schnoedel, Please check the updated question

Comment: Thanks! The exception (`TypeError`) should have a callstack. Can you expand the line in the log and show us the stack?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the same error and i was facing this issue as well in the ui5 versions 1.32.xx to 1.34.1 . However the issue seems to have been fixed 1.34.2 onwards.

Comment: But I am using Version 1.34.8, still facing the error